# Error code 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s). What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN db1.card_type = 'debit' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS DEBIT,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN db1.card_type = 'credit' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS CREDIT,
    DATE_FORMAT(Latest, '%Y-%m') AS Dato
FROM
    (SELECT 
        pp.debtor_id, pp.card_type, MAX(pp.created) AS Latest
    FROM
        capital.credit_card cc
    JOIN capital.card_to_debtor ctd ON cc.id = ctd.card_id
        AND debtor_id IN (SELECT 
            fs.debtor_id, fs.created, fs.reason
        FROM
            analysis.full_settlement fs
        WHERE
            ((reason = 'BANK_PAYMENT'
                OR fs.reason = 'CARD_PAYMENT')
                AND fs.amount < 0)
                OR fs.REASON = 'TRIVIAL_BALANCE'
                OR fs.id = 13793327
                OR fs.id = 7451808)
    JOIN analysis.full_settlement fs ON fs.debtor_id = ctd.debtor_id
    JOIN (SELECT 
        p.debtor_id, ccc.card_type, p.created
    FROM
        capital.payment p
    JOIN capital.card_subscription cs ON cs.id = p.subscription_id
    JOIN (SELECT 
        cc.id, ctd.card_id, cc.card_type, ctd.debtor_id
    FROM
        capital.card_to_debtor ctd
    JOIN capital.credit_card cc ON cc.id = ctd.card_id) ccc ON ccc.card_id = cs.card_id
        AND ccc.debtor_id = p.debtor_id) pp ON fs.debtor_id = pp.debtor_id
        AND pp.created <= fs.created
    GROUP BY pp.debtor_id , fs.created) db
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        p.debtor_id, ccc.card_type, p.created
    FROM
        capital.payment p
    JOIN capital.card_subscription cs ON cs.id = p.subscription_id
    JOIN (SELECT 
        cc.id, ctd.card_id, cc.card_type, ctd.debtor_id
    FROM
        capital.card_to_debtor ctd
    JOIN capital.credit_card cc ON cc.id = ctd.card_id) ccc ON ccc.card_id = cs.card_id
        AND ccc.debtor_id = p.debtor_id) db1 ON db1.debtor_id = db.debtor_id
        AND db1.created = db.Latest
GROUP BY YEAR(Latest) , MONTH(Latest)
```

Comment: Please be more specific. On which line does the error occur? Which operand? Don't just dump your code here and expect the users to figure out what you mean.

Comment: It doesn't tell me. Which is pretty frustrating

Comment: Then you have to trim down the query to identify the part where the error occurs. It's pretty hard to actually comprehend what you are trying to do with all the subselects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
debtor_id IN (SELECT 
            fs.debtor_id, fs.created, fs.reason
```

`debtor_id` is one column, so you can only compare it to one other column. Change it to

```
debtor_id IN (SELECT 
                fs.debtor_id FROM...
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!